# UIImagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo values missing in Info Dictonary

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-player, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I'm not able to get the value `(_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart and _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd)` in Info Dictionary delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` to pick the video from the gallery.Please check the o/p below for reference.

```
Info in User's Photo Gallery :

{
   UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie";
   UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/BD4C5E33-DD1B-4DEB-A2FC-61520F8111BB/tmp//trim.Bts3gk.MOV";
   UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=15EC8223-59ED-4FE0-8BAA-ECE3768CF16D&ext=mov";
}
```

But while recording the video, I can get the `(_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart and _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd)`.Please check the o/p below for reference.

```
Info in Own Video Recorder :

{
   UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie";
   UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/BD4C5E33-DD1B-4DEB-A2FC-61520F8111BB/tmp/capture-T0x1ed543d0.tmp.FuX9Bf/capturedvideo.MOV";
   "_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd" = "2.123703718185425";
   "_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart" = "0.7572222352027893";
}
```

Can you please give idea to get the `(_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart and _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd)` in Photo gallery.